# Vector initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm relatively new to C++/coding and I'm working on my final project for CS2. I'm trying to design a "recipe calculator" that will take in 3 ingredients(into a vector) then search through a recipe database for potential recipes.

Currently, I'm struggling with some basics, when I call the function that initializes the vector, it won't output the ingredients again in the main.
When I try to output the vector inside the actual function, it works. But I want to make sure the same vector is saved in "ingreds" in the main.

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    cout << "Hello! Welcome to Abby's Recipe Calculator." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option: 1 to search by ingredient or 2 to browse recipes..." << endl;
    cin >> y;

    vector <string> ingreds;
    ingreds.reserve(4); 

    if (y == 1)
    {
        ingredientvector(ingreds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ingreds.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << ingreds[i];
        }
    }


    //else if (y == 2)
    //{
    //call recipe function... 
    //}

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

vector<string> ingredientvector(vector<string> x)
{
    cout << "SEARCH BY INGREDIENT" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter up to three ingredients... " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        x.push_back("  ");
        getline(cin, x[i]);
        if (x[i] == "1")
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: I'd really advice you to better format the code and never do `using namespace std`.

Comment: thank you, and can I ask why? I've never been taught to do anything other than using namespace std

Comment: Re: using namespace std; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: authors write `using namespace std;` to save on printing costs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
vector<string> ingredientvector(vector<string> x)
```

By

```
void ingredientvector(vector<string>& x)
```

And don't return `x` at the end of `ingredientvector`. Passed by reference (`&`), the object can directly be modifier by the function).

---

Note: Your code could have worked, if you did:

```
ingreds = ingredientvector(ingreds);
```

Else, local `x` variable inside `ingredientvector` is filled, but has no effect on `ingreds` because it was passed by copy (`x` is a local copy of `ingreds` within `ingredientvector`). `ingreds` is only affected if `x` is returned by `ingredientvector` and then affected to `ingreds`.

But passing variable by references is definitely the right way to do here.

Answer (score 0):

When returning values, by default return them by value:

```
std::vector<string> ingredientvector()
{
  std::cout << "SEARCH BY INGREDIENT" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Please enter up to three ingredients... " << std::endl;
  std::vector<string> x;
  x.reserve(4); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    x.push_back("  ");
    getline(cin, x[i]);
    if (x[i] == "1")
    {
        break;
    }
  }  
  return x;
}
```

Used like this:

```
if (y == 1)
{
    const auto ingreds=ingredientvector();
    for (const auto& this_ingred : ingreds)
    {
        std::cout << this_ingred << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns `"1"` as an ingredient. It'd be better to getline into a string variable, and only call `push_back` if we got past that test.

Comment: I'm just showing OP how to return the value. The logic is meant to be the same as in OPs post.